# hide <option> with class

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, html-select

I'm sure this is really simple. But it just won't work for me.

I wrote a form that allows the user to select a month from a list using the tags:

```
<select> <option>
```

`onchange` the class `.gone` from the day `SELECT` is removed, thereby displaying the list. 
`onchanve` the class `.gone` from the year `INPUT` is removed, thereby displaying the year.

I used PHP to set the value for year to the current year. I want to take the value from month and addClass `.gone` to the `OPTION` tag of the 31st day (and 29 and 30 for february) so that February 30th etc. isn't an option. I will % the value of year by 4==0 to check leap year and then not addClass `.gone` to the 29th of february. Basic date select form.

The Problem: When I add class `.gone` to `OPTION` it is still displayed. I assumed this is simply me forgetting some basic principle of html. Nevertheless, I can't figure it out.

CSS:

```
.gone {display:none;}
```

I could also use this:

```
.hidden {visibility:hidden;}
```

but that still displays the space, so I didn't use it.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <link to css styles>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
       function showDay() {

           $("#day").removeClass("gone")
       }

       function showYear() {

           $("#year").removeClass("gone")
       }
    </script>


  </head>
  <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
         <td>
           <select id="month" onchange="showDay();">
              <option>January</option>
              <option>more months...yada...yada</option>
              <option>December</option>
           </select>
         </td>
         <td>
           <select class="gone" id="day" onchange="showYear();">
              <option></option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>more days</option>
              <option class="gone">31</option>
           </select>
         </td>
         <td>
              <input class="gone" type="text"  size="5" name="year" id="year" 
               value="<?php echo date("Y"); ?>"/>
         </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The onchange javascript and php work exactly how I want them too. I didn't bother writing any scripts to make the days appear or disappear yet because simply putting the `.gone` class in the `OPTION` tag didn't work. Is there a way to make it hidden or not selectable? Once I figure that out, I'll write the script to make it happen based on the month and year.

Thank you for all the help!

UPDATE!!!

Based on the answers received. I am going to disable the dates that I don't want selectable using javascript. From w3schools.com I got a sample script, which I modified slightly, and set to call onchange from the month SELECT.

```
function disableElement()
{
  var sel=document.getElementById("day")
  sel.options[30].disabled=true;
  sel.options[31].disabled=true;
}
```

It worked perfectly. Now the 30th and 31st day are not selectable!

Comment: You can't hide or style options, they are rendered by the OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The Problem: When I add class .gone to OPTION. it is still displayed. I assumed this is simply me forgetting some basic principle of html. Nevertheless, I can't figure it out.

Nope, `<option>`s just don't support styling via CSS. Either `disabled` it, or [remove it from the DOM entirely](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.removeChild).

Comment: Note that `disabled` `option`s are still rendered.

Comment: AHA!!! I knew there was something I was missing. Another route I was going to try, Is there a way I can get javascript to add <!-- in front of it so that it is made a comment and therefore not displayed? Then I'd do the dame for the back

Comment: Don't worry about commenting it. That's the wrong approach. Just remove it from the DOM entirely.

Comment: I updated my question to include this answer. It did exactly what I wanted. Also noted @Jan Dvorak that it is still rendered. But I like that its greyed out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `disabled` attribute to the option it will disable it making it not selectable

`<option disabled>Value</option>`

example: http://jsfiddle.net/BCk8m/

Comment: But it's still rendered, isn't it?